# How do I fix problem with trying to install Ubuntu? Black screen appears

Tags: installation, dual-boot, uefi, nomodeset

I'm trying to install Ubuntu version 13.04(x64) on a Desktop computer already running Win8 I'd like to dualboot. The system is 64-bit with UEFI. When I attempt to install Ubuntu from a burned DVD, I arrive at the menu that asks if I want to "try without installing", "install Ubuntu", and 2 other options I can't remember (not important).

If I choose any of the options (I'd like to try without installing but I've tried to install straight from this menu as well), the menu goes away and is replaced by a black screen. This problem has persisted no matter what options I've changed. I've disabled secureboot, fastboot, quickboot, updated my drivers and done everything else that I can think of/that has been suggested. The only thing that has been suggested that I have not done (besides give up) is boot nomodeset. I don't know how to boot nomodeset, and I don't know if it would fix the issue I'm having. If anyone could tell me how to do this I would really appreciate it. Also, if there are any other suggestions as to how I could possible fix the issue, I would love it

I looked at this question:

- [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

That post shows a purple screen that Displays the Ubuntu logo. When I try to run anything, the screen is completely black and the keyboard seems to be disabled. No matter what key I press nothing happens.

Every "fix" I've seen shows this purple Ubuntu boot screen (which I'm now assuming is grub 2). I don't get this purple screen. When I try to boot from a DVD, I get a black screen with 3 or 4 options. pressing F6 doesn't do anything and most of the people are saying I need to press F6 from the Grub2 menu and boot nomodeset. Is there Any way to do the same thing from this black menu that I'm getting (which I assume is Grub(archaic?)

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: That post shows a purple screen that Displays the Ubuntu logo. When I try to run anything, the screen is completely black and the keyboard seems to be disabled. No matter what key I press nothing happens.

Comment: Every "fix" I've seen shows this purple Ubuntu boot screen (which I'm now assuming is grub 2). I don't get this purple screen. When I try to boot from a DVD, I get a black screen with 3 or 4 options. pressing F6 doesn't do anything and most of the people are saying I need to press F6 from the Grub2 menu and boot nomodeset. Is there Any way to do the same thing from this black menu that I'm getting (which I assume is Grub(archaic?)

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought what happened  to me one time is the disk was bad  and it took me two days to figure that out crazy me  I don't know if that is your problem but might be